# Example TCP server written in Rust

Tags: tcp, rust

I'm looking for an example of a TCP server in Rust.

Either an 'hello world' or an echo server would be great.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/thomaslee/4753338

Comment: @rags: you should make an answer of that

Comment: @rags: actually, I decided to fix it up for Rust 0.7 and post it myself—feel free to answer it yourself if you're eager to, and I'll remove my copy of it. Your Gist could do with being updated, too.

Comment: See also https://github.com/shaladdle/learnrust/blob/master/echoserver.rs

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Here is a very simple example using `std::net`. It was developed against the current master of Rust and should work on 1.* also.

Be careful with this example; it is simplified; you may not want it to panic if binding, listening or accepting produce an error.

```rust
use std::io::Write;
use std::net::TcpListener;
use std::thread;

fn main() {
    let listener = TcpListener::bind("127.0.0.1:9123").unwrap();
    println!("listening started, ready to accept");
    for stream in listener.incoming() {
        thread::spawn(|| {
            let mut stream = stream.unwrap();
            stream.write(b"Hello World\r\n").unwrap();
        });
    }
}
```

Note the paradigm with regards to accepting; you must initiate the `accept()` request yourself (in this example we're using the `incoming()` iterator which just calls `accept()` each time), and so you get *real* control of what tasks there are.

In consequence, I've put the actual stream-handling code into a separate thread, but it needn't be for very short requests (it just means that you would not be able to handle a second request while handling the first); you could just as well remove the `thread::spawn(|| { ... })` about those two lines. The use of additional threads gives a certain degree of isolation, also; if the thread unwinds, the server as a whole will not die (bear in mind, however, that running out of memory or having a destructor panic while unwinding will cause the whole server to die).

Comment: This code doesn't compile any more, can you please update it? (I would but I am not sure how to spawn the task)

Comment: It again doesn't compile anymore on master. I figured as far as that TcpListener moved to std::net, but it appears the the process spawning and stream writing changed as well

Answer (score 8):

Simple TCP echo-server https://gist.github.com/seriyps/fd6d29442e16c44ba400

```
#![feature(phase)]
#[phase(plugin, link)] extern crate log;
extern crate green;
extern crate rustuv;

use std::io;
use std::os;
use std::io::{Listener,Acceptor,TcpStream};

// This is for green threads. If removed, will spawn 1 OS thread per client.
#[start]
fn start(argc: int, argv: *const *const u8) -> int {
    green::start(argc, argv, rustuv::event_loop, main)
}


fn main() {
    let host = "127.0.0.1";
    let port = 8080;

    let sock = io::TcpListener::bind(host, port).unwrap();
    let mut acceptor = sock.listen();
    for stream in acceptor.incoming() {
        match stream {
            Err(e) => warn!("Accept err {}", e),
            Ok(stream) => {
                spawn(proc() {
                    debug!("{}", handle_client(stream));
                })
            }
        }
    }
}

fn handle_client(mut stream: io::TcpStream) -> io::IoResult<()> {
    info!("New client {}", stream.peer_name());
    let mut buf = [0u8, ..4096];
    loop {
        let got = try!(stream.read(buf));
        if got == 0 {
            // Is it possible? Or IoError will be raised anyway?
            break
        }
        try!(stream.write(buf.slice(0, got)));
    }
    Ok(())
}
```

Comment: This no longer works - see my comment [here](https://gist.github.com/seriyps/fd6d29442e16c44ba400#gistcomment-1562789) for why.