# How do I handle parallel reads and writes on a TcpStream?

Tags: tcp, stream, telnet, rust

I read [Idiomatic way to handle writes to a TcpStream while waiting on read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21157789/idiomatic-way-to-handle-writes-to-a-tcpstream-while-waiting-on-read), but I'm still unsure of how to handle this. I'm connecting to a Rust binary via Telnet and would like to send "commands" and receive "status". Almost like a simple echo server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up [cloning the stream](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/net/struct.TcpStream.html#method.try_clone) and it's working fine:

```
let second_stream = stream.try_clone().expect("Cannot clone stream");
let mut reader = BufferedReader::new(second_stream);
let mut writer = BufferedWriter::new(stream);
```

Comment: Looks very wired

Answer (score 0):

Just an update for Rust 1.1, this method no longer works. To make this work, I used `stream.shutdown(Shutdown::Write)` when I was finished with writing to the server socket. I don't know how I would do this if I had to repeatedly read and write from the same connection.