# How to read and write to a TCPStream simultaneously?

Tags: tcp, rust

[This previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26621746/in-rust-how-do-i-handle-parallel-read-writes-on-a-tcpstream) does not work anymore since `TCPStream` does not have `clone()` anymore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`try_clone`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/net/struct.TcpStream.html#method.try_clone) to get multiple handles for the stream.