# How to store TcpStream with BufReader and BufWriter in a data structure

Tags: rust

I wanted a `TcpStream` shared by both a `BufReader` and a `BufWriter`, I found a solution in:
[If BufReader takes ownership of a stream, how can I read and write lines on it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35869078/if-bufreader-takes-ownership-of-a-stream-how-can-i-read-and-write-lines-on-it)

Now I want it in its own data structure, but I only got a partial answer from:
 
[Why can't I store a value and a reference to that value in the same struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32300132/why-cant-i-store-a-value-and-a-reference-to-that-value-in-the-same-struct)

### The desired implementation is violating ownership rules.

```rust
use std::io::{BufReader, BufWriter};
use std::net::TcpStream;

pub struct BufTcpStream<'a> {
    _socket: TcpStream,
    input:  BufReader<&'a TcpStream>;
    output: BufWriter<&'a TcpStream>;
}

impl<'a> BufTcpStream<'a> {
    pub fn new(socket: TcpStream) -> Self {
        Self{
            input : BufReader::new(&socket),
            output: BufWriter::new(&socket),
            _socket: socket,//                 <-- MOVE OF BORROWED VALUE HERE
        }
    }
}
```

To solve this problem, I had to ensure the `TcpStream` references will stay valid during all the structure lifetime, I used a `Pin<Box<TcpStream>>` to ensure it.

But the compiler still complain about the move of the borrowed value `socket`. To remove this barrier I used `std::meme::transmute()`.

Now, what i want to know is:

### Is this implementation safe?

```rust
use std::io::{BufReader, BufWriter};
use std::net::TcpStream;
use std::pin::Pin;

pub struct BufTcpStream<'a> {
    _socket: Pin<Box<TcpStream>>,
    input : BufReader<&'a TcpStream>,
    output: BufWriter<&'a TcpStream>,
}

impl<'a> BufTcpStream<'a> {
    pub fn new(socket: TcpStream) -> Self {
        let pin = Box::pin(socket);
        unsafe {
            Self{
                input : BufReader::new(std::mem::transmute(&*pin)),
                output: BufWriter::new(std::mem::transmute(&*pin)),
                _socket: pin,
            }
        }
    }
    pub fn reach(&mut self) -> (
        &mut BufReader<&'a TcpStream>,
        &mut BufWriter<&'a TcpStream>
    ) {
        (&mut self.input, &mut self.output)
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If BufReader takes ownership of a stream, how can I read and write lines on it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35869078/if-bufreader-takes-ownership-of-a-stream-how-can-i-read-and-write-lines-on-it)

Comment: You probably want something like that https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/pin/index.html#example-self-referential-struct, I don't know, if it's a good thing to do. I advise you to use something like https://docs.rs/bufstream/0.1.4/bufstream/

Comment: The code you've posted is not valid Rust syntax.

Comment: It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [MRE]. We can't tell what crates (and their versions), types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. It would make it easier for us to help you if you try to reproduce your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) if possible, otherwise in a brand new Cargo project, then [edit] your question to include the additional info. There are [Rust-specific MRE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here. Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use [`TcpStream::try_clone`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/net/struct.TcpStream.html#method.try_clone) to get a second stream:

> The returned `TcpStream` is a reference to the same stream that this object references. **Both handles will read and write the same stream of data**, and options set on one stream will be propagated to the other stream.

You can then wrap one in a reader and one in a writer:

```
use std::{
    io::{self, BufReader, BufWriter},
    net::TcpStream,
};

struct BufTcpStream {
    input: BufReader<TcpStream>,
    output: BufWriter<TcpStream>,
}

impl BufTcpStream {
    fn new(stream: TcpStream) -> io::Result<Self> {
        let input = BufReader::new(stream.try_clone()?);
        let output = BufWriter::new(stream);

        Ok(Self { input, output })
    }
}
```

See also:

- [How to read and write to a TCPStream simultaneously?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35969943/155423)
- [How do I handle parallel reads and writes on a TcpStream?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26621746/155423)

Comment: In case it's helpful for a future reader: in tokio's `TcpStream` there is `split` (or, `into_split`) to accomplish the same end goal. You can pass each returned half into a `BufReader` or `BufWriter`, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

### No. This implementation is not safe. For two reasons.

#### 1) A reference to the `TcpStream` can live longer than the structure itself

```rust
let bad_ref = {
    let buffer = BufTcpStream::new(...);
    let (i, o) = buffer.reach();
    *i.get_ref()
};// <-- buffer is dropped here
// bad_ref is now an invalid ref but the compiler won't see it
bad_ref.write(b"hello world").unwrap();
```

The `*i.get_ref()` is of type `&'a TcpStream`, but the `&'a` lifetime is never inferred by the compiler, so it does not take it in account.

**It can be fixed in the `reach()` method, by linking the lifetime of `self` to the returned references:**

```rust
fn reach<'b>(&'b mut self) -> (
    &mut BufReader<&'b TcpStream>,
    &mut BufWriter<&'b TcpStream>
) {
    (&mut self.input, &mut self.output)
}
```

#### 2) The `TcpStream` is dropped before `BufReader` and `BufWriter`

```rust
pub struct BufTcpStream<'a> {
    _socket: Pin<Box<TcpStream>>,//       First to be dropped   |
    input : BufReader<&'a TcpStream>,//   Second to be dropped  |
    output: BufWriter<&'a TcpStream>,//   Last to be dropped    V
}
```

**It can be fixed by placing `_socket` as the last element:**

```rust
pub struct BufTcpStream<'a> {
    input : BufReader<&'a TcpStream>,//   First to be dropped   |
    output: BufWriter<&'a TcpStream>,//   Second to be dropped  |
    _socket: Pin<Box<TcpStream>>,//       Last to be dropped    V
}
```

Actually, the `'a` lifetime in `struct BufTcpStream<'a>` is useless.
Lifetime of the unsafe references can be set to `'static`.

### Here is the fixed implementation:

```rust
use std::io::{BufReader, BufWriter};
use std::net::TcpStream;
use std::pin::Pin;

pub struct BufTcpStream {
    input : BufReader<&'static TcpStream>,
    output: BufWriter<&'static TcpStream>,
    _socket: Pin<Box<TcpStream>>,
}

impl BufTcpStream {
    pub fn new(socket: TcpStream) -> Self {
        let pin = Box::pin(socket);
        unsafe {
            Self{
                input : BufReader::new(std::mem::transmute(&*pin)),
                output: BufWriter::new(std::mem::transmute(&*pin)),
                _socket: pin,
            }
        }
    }
    pub fn reach<'b>(&'b mut self) -> (
        &mut BufReader<&'b TcpStream>,
        &mut BufWriter<&'b TcpStream>
    ) {
        unsafe {
            std::mem::transmute((&mut self.input, &mut self.output))
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to clone the stream (which has a performance impact and is not always possible as not all types are cloneable), and certainly no need for unsafe. We just need `BufReader` and `BufWriter` that forward `Write` and `Read`, respectively, to their inner stream. The default ones in std do not do that, but they do provide access to the inner stream, so we can use that:

```rust
use std::io::{BufRead, BufReader, BufWriter, IoSlice, IoSliceMut, Read, Result, Write};

pub struct MyBufReader<T: ?Sized> {
    inner: BufReader<T>,
}

impl<T: Read> MyBufReader<T> {
    pub fn new(inner: T) -> Self {
        Self { inner: BufReader::new(inner) }
    }
}

impl<T: Read + ?Sized> Read for MyBufReader<T> {
    fn read(&mut self, buf: &mut [u8]) -> Result<usize> {
        self.inner.read(buf)
    }

    fn read_vectored(&mut self, bufs: &mut [IoSliceMut<'_>]) -> Result<usize> {
        self.inner.read_vectored(bufs)
    }

    fn read_exact(&mut self, buf: &mut [u8]) -> Result<()> {
        self.inner.read_exact(buf)
    }

    fn read_to_end(&mut self, buf: &mut Vec<u8>) -> Result<usize> {
        self.inner.read_to_end(buf)
    }

    fn read_to_string(&mut self, buf: &mut String) -> Result<usize> {
        self.inner.read_to_string(buf)
    }
}

impl<T: Read + ?Sized> BufRead for MyBufReader<T> {
    fn fill_buf(&mut self) -> Result<&[u8]> {
        self.inner.fill_buf()
    }

    fn consume(&mut self, amt: usize) {
        self.inner.consume(amt)
    }
}

impl<T: Write + ?Sized> Write for MyBufReader<T> {
    fn write(&mut self, buf: &[u8]) -> Result<usize> {
        self.inner.get_mut().write(buf)
    }

    fn write_all(&mut self, buf: &[u8]) -> Result<()> {
        self.inner.get_mut().write_all(buf)
    }

    fn write_vectored(&mut self, bufs: &[IoSlice<'_>]) -> Result<usize> {
        self.inner.get_mut().write_vectored(bufs)
    }

    fn flush(&mut self) -> Result<()> {
        self.inner.get_mut().flush()
    }
}

pub struct MyBufWriter<T: ?Sized + Write> {
    inner: BufWriter<T>,
}

impl<T: Write> MyBufWriter<T> {
    pub fn new(inner: T) -> Self {
        Self { inner: BufWriter::new(inner) }
    }
}

impl<T: Write + ?Sized> Write for MyBufWriter<T> {
    fn write(&mut self, buf: &[u8]) -> Result<usize> {
        self.inner.write(buf)
    }

    fn write_all(&mut self, buf: &[u8]) -> Result<()> {
        self.inner.write_all(buf)
    }

    fn write_vectored(&mut self, bufs: &[IoSlice<'_>]) -> Result<usize> {
        self.inner.write_vectored(bufs)
    }

    fn flush(&mut self) -> Result<()> {
        self.inner.flush()
    }
}

impl<T: Write + Read + ?Sized> Read for MyBufWriter<T> {
    fn read(&mut self, buf: &mut [u8]) -> Result<usize> {
        self.inner.get_mut().read(buf)
    }

    fn read_vectored(&mut self, bufs: &mut [IoSliceMut<'_>]) -> Result<usize> {
        self.inner.get_mut().read_vectored(bufs)
    }

    fn read_exact(&mut self, buf: &mut [u8]) -> Result<()> {
        self.inner.get_mut().read_exact(buf)
    }

    fn read_to_end(&mut self, buf: &mut Vec<u8>) -> Result<usize> {
        self.inner.get_mut().read_to_end(buf)
    }

    fn read_to_string(&mut self, buf: &mut String) -> Result<usize> {
        self.inner.get_mut().read_to_string(buf)
    }
}

impl<T: Write + BufRead + ?Sized> BufRead for MyBufWriter<T> {
    fn fill_buf(&mut self) -> Result<&[u8]> {
        self.inner.get_mut().fill_buf()
    }

    fn consume(&mut self, amt: usize) {
        self.inner.get_mut().consume(amt)
    }
}
```

Now `MyBufReader<MyBufWriter<TcpStream>>` or `MyBufWriter<MyBufReader<TcpStream>>` will be both `Write` and `Read`.