# Separate TcpStream + SslStream into read and write components

Tags: multithreading, ssl, tcp, concurrency, rust

I'm trying to make client program that communicates with a server using a `TcpStream` wrapped by a `openssl::ssl::SslStream` (from [crates.io](https://crates.io/crates/openssl)). It should wait for `read`, and process data sent from the server if it was received **without delay**. At the same time, it should be able to send messages to the server regardless of reading.

I tried some methods such as

1. Passing single stream to both read and write threads. Both `read` and `write` methods require a mutable reference, so I couldn't pass a single stream to two threads.
2. I followed [In Rust how do I handle parallel read writes on a TcpStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26621746/in-rust-how-do-i-handle-parallel-read-writes-on-a-tcpstream), but `TcpStream` doesn't seem to have `clone` method, and neither does `SslStream`.
3. I tried making copy of `TcpStream` with `as_raw_fd` and `from_raw_fd` :

```
fn irc_read(mut stream: SslStream<TcpStream>) {
    loop {
        let mut buf = vec![0; 2048];
        let resp = stream.ssl_read(&mut buf);
        match resp {
            // Process Message
        }
    }
}

fn irc_write(mut stream: SslStream<TcpStream>) {
    thread::sleep(Duration::new(3, 0));
    let msg = "QUIT\n";
    let res = stream.ssl_write(msg.as_bytes());
    let _ = stream.flush();
    match res {
        // Process
    }
}

fn main() {
    let ctx = SslContext::new(SslMethod::Sslv23).unwrap();
    let read_ssl = Ssl::new(&ctx).unwrap();
    let write_ssl = Ssl::new(&ctx).unwrap();

    let raw_stream = TcpStream::connect((SERVER, PORT)).unwrap();
    let mut fd_stream: TcpStream;
    unsafe {
        fd_stream = TcpStream::from_raw_fd(raw_stream.as_raw_fd());
    }
    let mut read_stream = SslStream::connect(read_ssl, raw_stream).unwrap();
    let mut write_stream = SslStream::connect(write_ssl, fd_stream).unwrap();

    let read_thread = thread::spawn(move || {
        irc_read(read_stream);
    });

    let write_thread = thread::spawn(move || {
        irc_write(write_stream);
    });

    let _ = read_thread.join();
    let _ = write_thread.join();
}
```

this code compiles, but panics on the second `SslStream::connect`

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Failure(Ssl(ErrorStack([Error { library: "SSL routines", function: "SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO", reason: "unknown protocol" }])))', ../src/libcore/result.rs:788
stack backtrace:
   1:     0x556d719c6069 - std::sys::backtrace::tracing::imp::write::h00e948915d1e4c72
   2:     0x556d719c9d3c - std::panicking::default_hook::_{{closure}}::h7b8a142818383fb8
   3:     0x556d719c8f89 - std::panicking::default_hook::h41cf296f654245d7
   4:     0x556d719c9678 - std::panicking::rust_panic_with_hook::h4cbd7ca63ce1aee9
   5:     0x556d719c94d2 - std::panicking::begin_panic::h93672d0313d5e8e9
   6:     0x556d719c9440 - std::panicking::begin_panic_fmt::hd0daa02942245d81
   7:     0x556d719c93c1 - rust_begin_unwind
   8:     0x556d719ffcbf - core::panicking::panic_fmt::hbfc935564d134c1b
   9:     0x556d71899f02 - core::result::unwrap_failed::h66f79b2edc69ddfd
                        at /buildslave/rust-buildbot/slave/stable-dist-rustc-linux/build/obj/../src/libcore/result.rs:29
  10:     0x556d718952cb - _<core..result..Result<T, E>>::unwrap::h49a140af593bc4fa
                        at /buildslave/rust-buildbot/slave/stable-dist-rustc-linux/build/obj/../src/libcore/result.rs:726
  11:     0x556d718a5e3d - dbrust::main::h24a50e631826915e
                        at /home/lastone817/dbrust/src/main.rs:87
  12:     0x556d719d1826 - __rust_maybe_catch_panic
  13:     0x556d719c8702 - std::rt::lang_start::h53bf99b0829cc03c
  14:     0x556d718a6b83 - main
  15:     0x7f40a0b5082f - __libc_start_main
  16:     0x556d7188d038 - _start
  17:                0x0 - <unknown>
error: Process didn't exit successfully: `target/debug/dbrust` (exit code: 101)
```

The best solution I've found so far is to use nonblocking. I used `Mutex` on the stream and passed it to both threads. Then the reading thread acquires a lock and calls `read`. If there is no message it releases the lock so that the writing thread can use the stream. With this method, the reading thread does busy waiting, resulting in 100% CPU consumption. This is not the best solution, I think.

Is there a safe way to separate the read and write aspects of the stream?

Comment: Can you show the code that reproduces your concerns? It's hard for us to help without it.

Comment: To add to @E_net4's point, show us *what you have tried*, otherwise we are likely going to duplicate all the "possible ways" which already have "all failed".

Comment: Additionally, there's no `SslStream` in the standard library. You have to create a [MCVE]; we aren't going to search through every single crate to find one that *might* be the `SslStream` that you mean.

Comment: Thank you for comments. I've added details for my situation.

Comment: *"but `TcpStream` doesn't seem to have `clone` method"* — just search through the `TcpStream` documentation for "clone" and you'll find [`try_clone`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/net/struct.TcpStream.html#method.try_clone). Does that answer your question?

Comment: I'm sorry that I've missed that I could also use `try_clone`. I've managed to clone `TcpStream` to separate it into `BufReader` and `BufWriter`. However the communication is based on ssl, so I can't simply use reader and writer from on `TcpStream`. I guess I have to ask this to `SslStream`

Answer (score 1):

I accomplished the split of an SSL stream into a read and a write part by using Rust's [`std::cell::UnsafeCell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.UnsafeCell.html).

```
extern crate native_tls;

use native_tls::TlsConnector;
use std::cell::UnsafeCell;
use std::error::Error;
use std::io::Read;
use std::io::Write;
use std::marker::Sync;
use std::net::TcpStream;
use std::sync::Arc;
use std::sync::Mutex;
use std::thread;

struct UnsafeMutator<T> {
    value: UnsafeCell<T>,
}

impl<T> UnsafeMutator<T> {
    fn new(value: T) -> UnsafeMutator<T> {
        return UnsafeMutator {
            value: UnsafeCell::new(value),
        };
    }

    fn mut_value(&self) -> &mut T {
        return unsafe { &mut *self.value.get() };
    }
}

unsafe impl<T> Sync for UnsafeMutator<T> {}

struct ReadWrapper<R>
where
    R: Read,
{
    inner: Arc<UnsafeMutator<R>>,
}

impl<R: Read> Read for ReadWrapper<R> {
    fn read(&mut self, buf: &mut [u8]) -> Result<usize, std::io::Error> {
        return self.inner.mut_value().read(buf);
    }
}
struct WriteWrapper<W>
where
    W: Write,
{
    inner: Arc<UnsafeMutator<W>>,
}

impl<W: Write> Write for WriteWrapper<W> {
    fn write(&mut self, buf: &[u8]) -> Result<usize, std::io::Error> {
        return self.inner.mut_value().write(buf);
    }

    fn flush(&mut self) -> Result<(), std::io::Error> {
        return self.inner.mut_value().flush();
    }
}

pub struct Socket {
    pub output_stream: Arc<Mutex<Write + Send>>,
    pub input_stream: Arc<Mutex<Read + Send>>,
}

impl Socket {
    pub fn bind(host: &str, port: u16, secure: bool) -> Result<Socket, Box<Error>> {
        let tcp_stream = match TcpStream::connect((host, port)) {
            Ok(x) => x,
            Err(e) => return Err(Box::new(e)),
        };
        if secure {
            let tls_connector = TlsConnector::builder().build().unwrap();
            let tls_stream = match tls_connector.connect(host, tcp_stream) {
                Ok(x) => x,
                Err(e) => return Err(Box::new(e)),
            };
            let mutator = Arc::new(UnsafeMutator::new(tls_stream));
            let input_stream = Arc::new(Mutex::new(ReadWrapper {
                inner: mutator.clone(),
            }));
            let output_stream = Arc::new(Mutex::new(WriteWrapper { inner: mutator }));

            let socket = Socket {
                output_stream,
                input_stream,
            };
            return Ok(socket);
        } else {
            let mutator = Arc::new(UnsafeMutator::new(tcp_stream));
            let input_stream = Arc::new(Mutex::new(ReadWrapper {
                inner: mutator.clone(),
            }));
            let output_stream = Arc::new(Mutex::new(WriteWrapper { inner: mutator }));

            let socket = Socket {
                output_stream,
                input_stream,
            };
            return Ok(socket);
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let socket = Arc::new(Socket::bind("google.com", 443, true).unwrap());

    let socket_clone = Arc::clone(&socket);

    let reader_thread = thread::spawn(move || {
        let mut res = vec![];
        let mut input_stream = socket_clone.input_stream.lock().unwrap();
        input_stream.read_to_end(&mut res).unwrap();
        println!("{}", String::from_utf8_lossy(&res));
    });

    let writer_thread = thread::spawn(move || {
        let mut output_stream = socket.output_stream.lock().unwrap();
        output_stream.write_all(b"GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n").unwrap();
    });

    writer_thread.join().unwrap();
    reader_thread.join().unwrap();
}
```

Comment: Idiomatic Rust does not use `return` at the end of blocks / functions.

Comment: Why `UnsafeCell` instead of something easier to get right like `Cell` or `RefCell`?

Comment: This code is **unsafe** because [it allows for mutable aliasing](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=a662db7712da6d30d475773df5e1e598&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015) from code that only uses safe functions.

Comment: @Shepmaster: I re-checked the code, it compiles. I use Ubuntu 18.04, Rust stable toolchain, rustc 1.27.0. Note: You have to add the crate [native_tls](https://crates.io/crates/native-tls) to your dependencies and fulfill the requirments for native_tls on your system (see doc).

Comment: Yes, UnsafeMutator and UnsafeCell is unsafe - as indicated by the name.

Comment: ***But that "the code" is unsafe, is not exactly true!***

The key point is the API that is exposed to the user - the `pub struct Socket`. By using two [Mutex](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.21.0/std/sync/struct.Mutex.html) it allows only one read and one write access in parallel to the underlying stream. As far as I now this is fine for streams and does not break any mutability rules (tested with tcp and ssl stream).

So, unsafe access to the stream via `UnsafeMutator` is controlled by the `Mutex` objects and therefore safe again.

Comment: [The code you have provided does not compile](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=a548b89700b94c2c643ebab7b83f54b3&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015). You have neglected to provide any version information, so that seems like a likely candidate for the problem.

Comment: @Bernd Having two mutable references to the same object is undefined behaviour (not just "unsafe but OK if you know what you're doing" but actually dangerous), even if you never modify the actual object through those references. The optimisations that could be enabled by Rust's lifetime model are currently turned off because of a bug in them in LLVM, so if that gets fixed and turned back on then undefined behaviours from lifetime mistakes like this could suddenly start exploding.

Comment: @Bernd The relevant line of the documentation in [`std::cell::UnsafeCell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.UnsafeCell.html): "There is *no* legal way to obtain aliasing `&mut`, not even with `UnsafeCell<T>`."